# Assigning class properties from locationManager:didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have a class that has a property of

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* test1;
```

.m file

```
-(void)doStuff
{
userLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]]init]; //has been synthesized already
userLocationManager.delegate = self;
userLocationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
userLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[userLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
NSLog(@"%@",self.test1); //logs (null)
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
self.test1 = @"Hello!";
[userLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Then, I have a class that initializes the locationmanager, etc. and I eventually call `locationManager:didUpdateLocations.` I then do a simple `self.test1=@"Hello"` within this method, just to see if I can assign strings from that function. In another method I NSLog `self.test1`, to see if it was updated, but I get `(null)`, in the console. Is `locationManager:didUpdateLocations` async or what?
Thanks!
~Carpetfizz

EDIT: Added some more code to make the question clearer. Please excuse any syntax errors as I physically copied the code from another computer. It compiles fine.

Comment: Can you put more info? It should work, it's not async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your class is the delegate of CLLocationManagerDelegate.

Comment: Did you set the delegation somewhere in your .m file like viewDidLoad? The code should be something like this;

CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: Where you log your string might be called before your delegate method and that's might be why your are getting null result. Simply NSLog something in didUpdateLocations to see if it is called in your class.

Comment: Updated my code. Also, I can confirm that that method fires. What was strange is that it NSLogs AFTER `Line 8` in my posted code.

Comment: Okay, the problem you have is exactly what I have told you. After [userLocationManager startUpdatingLocation] line, your NSLog is fired simultaneously with your delegate method. Therefore, your NSLog is fired before your string is set.

Comment: Oh this makes a lot of sense, thanks! But how do I fix it, or make sure that the string is set?

Comment: You can use your delegate method (didUpdateLocations) for setting, logging, initiating and these kind of actions for your variables. Otherwise, since its a delegation, your other methods cannot know when your delegate method gets into the work so that whatever you do in your delegate method should not be used in other methods in your class. By the way, it is an asynchronous task.

Comment: Okay, this makes a lot of sense, I was thrown off by @AntonioMG's comment: "Can you put more info? It should work, it's not async. – Antonio MG 51 mins ago
"